# How to change theme in jstree to own?

Tags: javascript, jstree

Can I change the default theme in jstree to my own, css will be the same, i just need to change the png file for sprites?

Here is what I tried:

```
"core" : {
            "themes" : {
                "name" : 'oxford',
                "url" : true,
                "dir" : "additional/jstree_theme",
                "stripes" : true,
                "icons" : false
            }

"plugins" : ["themes", "ui", "search", "types", "checkbox" ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't need to use url and dir, just set css manually in html

Comment: can you please give example? if you find some time please check my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55185032/js-tree-customization-in-css-styles