# JS Tree customization in CSS styles

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a tree structure list for one of my tasks. I am planning to use [JS-TREE plugin](https://www.jstree.com/docs/json/) for this purpose. Still the plugin comes with lot of features, I have to do few styling changes to match the given design.

This is the [code pen](https://codepen.io/JGSpark/pen/XGEZRe) link which I tried so for,

```
1. Change the plus-square with angle-down icon
2. Change the minus-square with angle-up icon
3. change the square-filled-grey icon(will come if any few of child nodes selected) with minus-square icon
4. Hover blue highlighting not needed
```

Any way to customize this? OR Any super hit plugins from your experience?

Answer (score 1):

So, it looks like they're using a sprite map and changing the background position to select which icon appears

I was able to move this

```
.jstree-proton .jstree-anchor > .jstree-undetermined {
    background-position: -38px -5px;
}
```

This satisfied #3. If you inspect any of the icons (jstree-icon class), you'll see a background assigned to 32.png. You'll have to change the positioning for icons that exist there. For the angle up and down you'll have to hide the background image they supplied and insert your own icons

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to create a css file and overwrite the jstree class setting "!important" at the end of the rules you want to change? For me it worked because I needed to change the jstree-rename-input class like this.

```css
.jstree-rename-input {
    border: none !important;
    width: 250px !important;
  }
```

As far as i investigated, this is also the official answer provided by jsTree creator.